# insert numbers to pointer array in function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I have a code I wrote, basically what it does is get the size of a dynamic array named `array` and numbers to insert to it from the user, then send the array to the function `PartialSums`.

`PartialSums` is supposed to take the number from `array[i]`, add it to `sum`, then put `sum` in `newarray[i]`, until the end of the array which is `arraysize`, after that it should return `newarray` back to `main` and print both of the arrays.

I guess you can think of it as kind of factorial of each cell of `array` with the cells before but it sums the numbers instead of multiply them.

Example for what should be in `newarray` at the end:

```
arraysize = 5
array = 1,2,3,4,5

newarray should be: 1,3,6,10,15 
just to show what it looks like mathematically: 1,2+1,3+2+1,4+3+2+1,5+4+3+2+1
```

and this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *PartialSums(int arrsize, int *array) {
    int *newarray;
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    newarray = (int *)malloc(arrsize * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
        sum = sum + array[i];
        newarray[i] = sum;
    }
    return newarray;
}

int main() {
    int *array;
    int *newarray;
    int arrsize;
    int num;
    int flag = 1;
    int i;
    do {
        printf("please insert amount of numbers to enter\n");
        scanf("%d", &arrsize);
        array = (int *)malloc(arrsize * sizeof(int));
        newarray = (int *)malloc(arrsize * sizeof(int));
        /* if memory cannot be allocated */
        if (array == NULL || newarray == NULL) {
            printf("Error! memory not allocated.\n\n");
            flag = 0;
        }
    } while (flag = 0);

    for (i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
        printf("please insert a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        array[i] = num; 
    }
    *newarray = PartialSums(arrsize, array);
    printf("this is the main array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
        if (i < arrsize - 1)
            printf(",");
    }
    printf("\nthis is the new array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
        printf("%d", newarray[i]);
        if (i < arrsize - 1)
            printf(",");
    }
    free(array);
    free(newarray);
    return 0;
}
```

up until the sum part everything works but for some reason the print is this:

this is the new array:  `18825296,0,0,0,0`

the first number changes every time

I am guessing the problem is in the function, which means something is wrong with inserting `sum` to `newarray`

or its something with returning `newarray` back to `main`

the problem is I don't know what I did wrong and hope you guys can help me understand.

Comment: Oops, I would advise not to retry after a memory allocation unless you made sure to have freed something. As memory is now a cheap thing, most applications or libraries are not well prepared to face a memory allocation error. So when it happens the best is to close everything before the kernel panics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in your program:

1. The loop condition in the do-while loop should be `flag == 0`. With `flag = 0` you assign zero to *flag* and the loop never repeats.
2. The assignment should be

   ```
   newarray = PartialSums(arrsize, array);
   ```

   That is, without pointer dereference.
3. As pointed out by WhozCraig you have a memory leak when *newarray* is assigned the result of *PartialSums*; you don't need to allocate memory for *newarray* in the main function.

You should also make sure that the input is valid by inspecting the return value of *scanf*. It is also a good idea to print a newline after the result to make sure it is displayed correctly also on non-Windows systems.

*Tip*: When working with dynamically allocated arrays it is useful to keep the name of an array and its length together. Therefor I always use the array name with the suffix *Len* for an array length variable. In your case it would be *arrayLen* and *newarrayLen*. With this approach you never mix up different array lengths (even though in this program there is only one length).

Comment: And fix the memory leak once you fix the second. The allocation for `newarray= (int*) malloc(...` in `main` is pointless; the `PartialSums` function does it for you.

Comment: thanks that worked, i didn't even noticed i assigned in the do-while insted of condition and malloc twice on newarray

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors:

- the logic for the `do` / `while` loop is broken: the test `flag = 0` **sets** `flag` to `0` instead of comparing to `0`. Furthermore, you must set `flag` to `1` inside the loop. It is actually simpler to use a `for(;;)` loop and explicitly break from it if you can allocate the array.
- it serves no purpose to allocate `newarray` in `main()`.
- memory allocation failure should be tested in `PartialSums`.
- storing the return value from `PartialSums` should be just `newarray = PartialSums(arrsize,array);` As coded, you are patching the first entry of the `newarray` you allocated in `main()`, which explains the observed behavior.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *PartialSums(int arrsize, int *array) {
    int *newarray = (int *)malloc(arrsize * sizeof(int));
    if (newarray != NULL) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
            sum = sum + array[i];
            newarray[i] = sum;
        }
    }
    return newarray;
}

int flush_input(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

int main() {
    int *array;
    int *newarray;
    int arrsize;
    for (;;) {
        printf("please insert amount of numbers to enter:\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &arrsize) != 1 || arrsize <= 0) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            if (flush_input() == EOF)
                return 1;
            continue;
        }
        array = (int *)malloc(arrsize * sizeof(int));
        /* if memory cannot be allocated */
        if (array == NULL) {
            printf("Error! memory not allocated.\n\n");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrsize;) {
        printf("please insert a number for array[%d]: ", i);
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1) {
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            if (flush_input() == EOF)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("This is the main array: ");
    printf("%d", array[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < arrsize; i++) {
        printf(",%d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    newarray = PartialSums(arrsize, array);
    if (newarray) {
        printf("This is the new array: ");
        printf("%d", newarray[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < arrsize; i++) {
            printf(",%d", newarray[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(newarray);
    } else {
        printf("Memory allocation failure\n");
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i never seen a for (;;) looks like that, how do you work with it without the assignment and condition inside?

Comment: `for(;;)` is a for ever loop: no condition means no ending condition. This loop will continue until explicitly broken from with a `break` or `return` statement.